# Reading a large JSON from Facebook

Tags: php, json, facebook, facebook-graph-api

How can I read several values with the same name from a JSON from Facebook, when I use this code:

```
$urlamandar = 'https://graph.facebook.com/'.$user."?access_token=".$access_token;
$content = file_get_contents($urlamandar);
$obj = json_decode($content, true);
$obj = json_decode($content);
```

It displays this:

```
{
   "id": "XXXXXXXX",
   "name": "Ricardo Capistran",
   "first_name": "Ricardo",
   "last_name": "Capistran",
   "gender": "male",
   "locale": "es_MX",
   "username": "richycapy"
}
```

And since because there is only one ID, one NAME, one USERNAME, etc, Its quite simple place them in vars like so:

```
$fbuserid = $obj->{'id'};
$fbname = $obj->{'name'};
$fbusername = $obj->{'username'};
$fbemail = $obj->{'email'};
$fbbirthday = $obj->{'birthday'};
```

But when it comes to larger files like this code:

```
$urlamandar = 'https://graph.facebook.com/'.$user.'/albums?access_token='.$access_token;
```

Its displays a way bigger array like so:

```
{
   "data": [
      {
         "id": "10150732237818223",
         "from": {
            "name": "Ricardo Capistran",
            "id": "XXXXXXX"
         },
         "name": "EnterateNorte.com Photos",
         "link": "https://www.facebook.com/album.php?fbid=10150732237818223&id=743158222&aid=457026",
         "privacy": "custom",
         "count": 31,
         "type": "app",
         "created_time": "2012-03-11T02:44:42+0000",
         "updated_time": "2014-01-07T03:13:24+0000",
         "can_upload": false
      },
      {
         "id": "440168313222",
         "from": {
            "name": "Ricardo Capistran",
            "id": "743158222"
         },
         "name": "Timeline Photos",
         "link": "https://www.facebook.com/album.php?fbid=440168313222&id=743158222&aid=220377",
         "cover_photo": "10151730849598223",
         "privacy": "everyone",
         "count": 175,
         "type": "wall",
         "created_time": "2010-06-30T22:38:45+0000",
         "updated_time": "2014-01-01T02:09:11+0000",
         "can_upload": false
      },
      {
         "id": "10150797320378223",
         "from": {
            "name": "Ricardo Capistran",
            "id": "743158222"
         },
         "name": "Instagram Photos",
         "link": "https://www.facebook.com/album.php?fbid=10150797320378223&id=743158222&aid=466555",
         "cover_photo": "10151695050098223",
         "privacy": "friends",
         "count": 37,
         "type": "app",
         "created_time": "2012-04-09T23:50:08+0000",
         "updated_time": "2013-12-29T08:29:15+0000",
         "can_upload": false
      }
   ],
   "paging": {
      "cursors": {
         "after": "NDM1NjY5NjI4MjIy",
         "before": "MTAxNTA3MzIyMzc4MTgyMjM="
      },
      "next": "https://graph.facebook.com/*my_id*/albums?access_token=*access_token*&limit=25&after=NDM1NjY5NjI4MjIy"
   }
}
```

And I would need the “name” and “id” off all the albums, so then I can repeat this same procedure with the containing pictures

Obviously it has way more albums, I just cut it after 3 just to explain my self…

Is there a way to place them in vars? With a  php “for each” some how

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like

```
$obj = json_decode($content, true);

$array_album = array();
foreach($obj['data'] as $key=>$val){
    $array_album[] = array("id"=>$val["id"],"name"=>$val["name"]);
    echo "ID : ".$val["id"]. " NAME : ".$val["name"] ;
    echo "<br />";
}
print_r($array_album); // This will have all the id and names
```

If you dont want to store in array then the names and id will appear in the above loop and you can do whatever you want with those values. Or use the array $array_album and loop through if you want to use it later.